# How to update and target the right index in an array which is nested in an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following react state, I want to update the second value not the whole object and I don't want to use an object as a value either, for now I can only change the whole object but not the specific wanted value how to target and update the wanted index.

```js
// State 
const [state, setState] = useState({
    element: [false, 'starter text']
 });
  
// Update State logic
 setState({ ...state, element: [(element[1] = 'updated text')] });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When updating state in React you shallow copy the state, and nested state, that you are updating. For arrays this means you shallow copy the array.

```
// State 
const [state, setState] = useState({
  element: [false, 'starter text']
});
  
// Update State logic
setState(state => ({
  // shallow copy any previous root-level state
  ...state,

  // shallow copy the previous state's element array
  // when the mapped index matches the index you want to update
  // return the updated value, otherwise return existing value
  element: state.element.map((el, i) => i === 1 ? 'updated text' : el)
}));
```

If the array was an array of objects then you need to shallow copy them as well, then update the nested property.

Example:

```
element: state.element.map(
  (el, i) => i === 1
    ? {
      ...el,
      nestedProperty: 'updated text'
    }
    : el
)
```

I know this [Immutable Update Patterns](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns) doc is from Redux, but is solves many common React state update issues.

Comment: tbh I tried to use spread operator again after element but it didn't work.. now this solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new state state as [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-forest-p0dm1?file=/src/App.js:177-345)

```
   setState(oldState => {
     const newState = { ...oldState, element: [ ...oldState.element ]};
     newState.element[1] = "updated text";
     return newState;
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). Since an array is an Object with indices as its properties, you can do this:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const updatedArr = Object.assign([], arr, { 1: 10 }); // Update value at index 1.

console.log(arr);
console.log(updatedArr);
```

Comment: With the [Change Array by copy proposal](//github.com/tc39/proposal-change-array-by-copy) this can be simplified to `const updatedArr = arr.with(1, 10);`.